# How to create a ffmpeg filter that zooms by a set value over a time while playing the video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to create a zoom effect where I start at `1 * inputwidth` and end with `1.1 * inputwidth` over a set time.

I tried using [`zoompan`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) but it:

- pauses the frame, zooms in over the amount of time specified, continues sound while zooming.
- zooms to the top-left corner, instead of center.
- leaves the frame smaller than it was before. Do I need to upscale afterwards?

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
-vf "fps=60,zoompan=z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)':d=1,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
```

I tried using [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) with [`crop`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), but then I get the error shown below. I assume this isn't to be as a function of time.

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
-vf "fps=60, scale='t/5*2*iw':-1, crop='iw/2*t/5':'ih/2*t/5'" out.mp4

Expressions with frame variables 'n', 't', 'pos' are not valid in init eval_mode.
```

If there's an other tool besides ffmpeg, that would be fine, except it should not be a gui-only way.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the right direction for what you want. There are a few things off with the commands you've specified

1. `zoompan` itself needs an `fps` **option**. The `fps` **filter** just interpolates the outcome of `zoompan`. You need to add `fps=60` to `zoompan` (match this to the input video).

   ```
   ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
   -vf "zoompan=fps=60:z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)':d=1,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
   ```

This will make the video not go out of sync.

2. the `top-left` zoom, is because `x` and `y` are both 0. To zoom at center add `x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'`

   ```
   ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
   -vf "zoompan=fps=60:z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
   ```
3. Assuming your video is bigger than 720p, the default for `zoompan` output size is [`s=hd720`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan:%7E:text=Set%20the%20output%20image%20size%2C%20default%20is%20%E2%80%99hd720%E2%80%99.) that's why it's smaller. To keep it in 1080p add `s=hd1080`

   ```
   ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
   -vf "zoompan=fps=60:z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=hd1080,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
   ```

This should be the full command

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
    -vf "zoompan=fps=60:z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=hd1080,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are working with a video already at `fps=60`, if not, that setting simply speeds up the video, leaving any audio, running at normal speed. fps should be set to whatever the video already is, unless I'm missing something.